# How to improve the performance of frequent querying of a table in sqlalchemy?

Tags: performance, sqlalchemy

I have a table inheriting from another one and with more than 10,000 rows and 10 columns.
I am reading more than 10,000 items from the Input. For each item I query the table to see if the data is not there. 
In this case I insert it to into the table.
A simplified example is as follows:

```
class Port(Interface):
    __tablename__ = 'ports'
    Int_Class_ID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('interfaceitems.Int_Class_ID', ondelete='cascade'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'ports',
    }
    Name = Column(Text)
    Locked = Column(Boolean)
    UniqueIdentifier = Column(Text, index=True)
```

Then I do:

```
portList = Session.query(Port).filter(Port.UniqueIdentifier == ID).all()
```

Which will be called for example 10,000 times.
But this is very slow, it takes 3 Minutes, which for the application of the code and the frequency it will be executed is not satisfying.
Is there any way to improve the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are reading the IDs and then calling Query for each ID individually.  This will be extremely slow, and you want to read a much larger list of items at a time.  The way I usually do this is to use chunks; that way you definitely have lots of items per query, but you don't load down the system with too many ids in one query:

```
list_of_ids = list(input_ids)
while list_of_ids:
    chunk = list_of_ids[0:1000]
    list_of_ids = list_of_ids[1000:]
    for port_object in session.query(Port).filter(Port.uniqueidentifier.in_(chunk)):
        process_object(port_object)
```

with the above, instead of emitting 10000 queries for one row each, you only emit ten queries for 1000 rows each.  It should run pretty quickly.

if the problem is elsewhere, like reading all 10K rows is too slow, and you can't work around emitting many queries with many rows, the tips in [orm slowness](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/faq/performance.html#result-fetching-slowness-orm) will help.   The upcoming [baked query](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3054/new-idea-for-bake) feature will also help with the production of the SQL string from the query, though that doesn't seem like the issue here.